# About abstract classes and passing objects

Tags: dart, abstract-class

```
void main() {
  final square = Square(side: 10);
  final circle = Circle(radius: 100);

  printArea(square);
  printArea(circle);
}

void printArea(Shape shape) {
  print(shape.area());
}

abstract class Shape {
  double area();
}

class Square implements Shape {
  Square({this.side});
  double side;

  double area() => side * side;
}

class Circle implements Shape {
  Circle({this.radius});
  double radius;

  double area() => radius * radius;
}
```

My question is inside printArea(Shape shape) is that "Shape" type of abstract class that I have created in the code? And does creating objects from a class that implements the abstract class, does those object becomes a type of abstract class "Shape"? Otherwise how is it possible to pass those created Objects as an argument ,assigning to the "Shape shape"?

Answer (score 0):

```
void printArea(Shape shape) {
  print(shape.area());
}
```

This means you take any object like `Shape` or an object which implements or extends from `Shape`. Since objects extending or implementing `Shape` are going to have the same properties and methods as `Shape` you can accept any object as long the object will behave like a `Shape`.

`abstract` class just means you can't make a object from this class since the class is allowed to specify methods which are not implemented.

When you create a class which extends or implements from an another class (abstract or not) it will be part of a class hierarchy. E.g. your `Circle` are a `Shape` but also a `Object` since all classes automatically will extends from the `Object` class:
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-core/Object-class.html